# Poor query performance in MySQL join with Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query that consistently takes 7 seconds to complete:

```
SELECT g.GroupID, g.GroupName, count(s.EventDate) AS Total 
FROM Groups g 
LEFT JOIN Schedule s 
ON g.GroupID = s.GroupID 
WHERE g.OrganizationID = 2 
AND g.IsActive = 1 
AND IFNULL(g.IsDeleted,0) = 0 
AND IFNULL(g.IsHidden,0) = 0 
AND (s.EventDate > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 0 HOUR) OR g.CreateDate > DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY), INTERVAL 0 HOUR)) 
GROUP BY g.GroupID, g.GroupName 
ORDER BY s.EventDate, g.GroupName;
```

I already have the following indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE Groups ADD INDEX (OrganizationID);
ALTER TABLE Groups ADD INDEX (IsActive);
ALTER TABLE Groups ADD INDEX (CreateDate);
ALTER TABLE Groups ADD INDEX (IsDeleted);
ALTER TABLE Groups ADD INDEX (IsHidden);
ALTER TABLE Groups ADD INDEX (GroupName);
ALTER TABLE Schedule ADD INDEX (EventDate);
```

Before the indexes were added the query took 18 seconds, so it's a huge improvement already. But I cannot understand why this query is still taking so long. The largest table in the join is `Schedule`, which has 13,216 records--not a huge table! The other tables are much smaller.

EXPLAIN results:
[image]

What can I do to improve my query performance?

Comment: What does the execution plan say?

Comment: Why are you doing a Date_add of 0 hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is query:

```
SELECT g.GroupID, g.GroupName, count(s.EventDate) AS Total 
FROM Groups g LEFT JOIN
     Schedule s 
     ON g.GroupID = s.GroupID 
WHERE g.OrganizationID = 2 AND
      g.IsActive = 1 AND
      IFNULL(g.IsDeleted,0) = 0 AND
      IFNULL(g.IsHidden,0) = 0 AND
      (s.EventDate > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 0 HOUR) OR g.CreateDate > DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY), INTERVAL 0 HOUR)) 
GROUP BY g.GroupID, g.GroupName 
ORDER BY s.EventDate, g.GroupName;
```

The best index for this query is a composite index on `groups`:  `groups(OrganizationId, IsActive, IsDeleted, IsHidden, CreateDate, GroupId)`.  The last three columns are for covering the `where` clause.  And then an index on `schedule(GroupId, EventDate)`.  The lack of index on `schedule(GroupId)` is probably the root of your performance problems.

Next, you are ordering by `s.EventDate`.  This doesn't make sense.  You are not selecting `s.eventDate` and it is ill defined when there is more than one value.

I don't understand what the double `date_add()` is supposed to be accomplishing.  Adding `interval 0 hour` doesn't do anything.  These operations do not affect performance, but they look awkward.

Comment: I added the composite index for Groups and it didn't help at all. Same speed. Then I added the composite for schedule(GroupId, EventDate) and WOW - query runs in 47ms now!! Thanks so much. Ordering by eventdate does make sense in the context of my app. The interval 0 hour is dynamic and sometimes there is a value there. Just in this example there wasn't.

Comment: Pretty good indeed. Shazam!!! My poor users have been tolerating this for 6 months. Shame on me...